# Angular $http post need any returning error to bubble up and what is .post(`${myurl}` ticks with french braces

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, http-post

Few problems

I don't believe that is post is getting me enough to bubble up errors, what can i do instead?

```
return $http.post(`${myUrl}/api/request`, 
                    data, 
                    {myApiResponse: true});
```

While I know in Angular 2 that the ticks `.....`  are used for the multiline in templateUrl references ,  I don't see any references to this in Angular 1.

Yes, i'm using Ionic mobile, but I assumed it has nothing to do with ionic.

what does this mean?

```
  `${myUrl}..`     

  `${ ??
```

Comment: take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: As pointed by qwerty_igor, these are template literals. Let me add that if you're not using a transpiler like Babel, you should probably avoid using ES6 features for Cordova apps and Webapps. (because of lack of support)